# How find this system equation

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

> Let $x,y,z\in {\mathbb R}$, and such $x \neq y \neq z$. Solve this system equation:
>   $$
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{ccccccl}
>     x & + & y & + & z         & = & 3xy
> \\[1mm]
> x^{2} & + & y^{2} & + & z^{2} & = &3yz
> \\[1mm]
> x^{3} & + & y^{3} & + & z^{3} & = & 3xz
> \end{array}\right.
> $$

$$
\mbox{My idea: Since}\quad
x + y + z = 3xy\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} + 2xy + 2yz + 2xz = 9x^{2}y^{2}
$$
$$
\mbox{then we have}\quad
5xz + 2xy + 2yz = 9x^{2}y^{2}
$$

This is from china The Olympic problem in Zhejiang.

It is said this system equation have no solution, but I can't prove it, maybe can use inequality to prove it ?.

Comment: You could just try to sub in from the top down and reach a contradiction. i.e.$z = 3xy-x-y$ into $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3yz$ and then try to isolate $x$ or $y$ and plug into the 3rd equation.

Comment: Newton's Identities give $2yz = 9xy^2 - 9y^2z + 2z$, though I doubt this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram Alpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bx%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%2B%20z%5E2%20-%203*y*z%20%3D0%2C%20x%2By%2Bz-3*x*y%20%3D%200%2Cx%5E3%2By%5E3%2Bz%5E3-3*x*z%3D0%7D) there are 4 solutions, 2 of which you can eliminate because you suppose that they're different.

It is not an analytical solution, but at least it will guide you in the right direction.

The first 2 equations are usual conics for which the solution can be obtained analytically [relatively nicely](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bx%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%2B%20z%5E2%20-%203*y*z%20%3D0%2C%20x%2By%2Bz-3*x*y%20%3D%200%7D). Then it is a question of using that parametrization in the last equation to find binding solutions for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following Maxima version

```
Maxima 5.25.1 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp GNU Common Lisp (GCL) GCL 2.6.8 (a.k.a. GCL)
```

I try to solve it by using a Groebner basis. I do the calculations by using a CAS ([Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)). The source code can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/eq). 
$p1$, $p2$ and $p3$ are the three given polynomials. 
$gb$ is a Groebner basis calculated by the CAS for these three polynomials. 
$gb$ is a list of polynomials.

```
(%i3) load(grobner)$
Loading maxima-grobner $Revision: 1.6 $ $Date: 2009-06-02 07:49:49 $
(%i4) p1:-3*x*y+z+y+x$
(%i5) p2:-3*y*z+z^2+y^2+x^2$
(%i6) p3:-3*x*z+z^3+y^3+x^3$
(%i7) gb:poly_reduced_grobner([p1,p2,p3],[x,y,z]);
(%o7) [-4767660*z^10-14511474*z^9-2093445*z^8+29411046*z^7+17677242*z^6
                    -15031881*z^5-9650244*z^4-1068394*z^3+17405*z^2+17405*y*z,
       -81*z^11-243*z^10-27*z^9+495*z^8+279*z^7-255*z^6-148*z^5-19*z^4-z^3,
       -266402844*z^10-762512859*z^9+18497646*z^8+1631905623*z^7+692505936*z^6
                      -947985525*z^5-361760418*z^4-4404204*z^3+261075*z^2
                      -34810*z-34810*y-34810*x,
       -14391189*z^10-42869331*z^9-3828627*z^8+88209945*z^7+47711907*z^6
                     -46704285*z^5-25500816*z^4-2610199*z^3-10443*z^2
                     -6962*y^2]
```

The second of the polynomials if the Groebner basis is a polynomial only in $z$. 
I call this polynomial$gbz$ and try to find its zeros. Maxima finds two solutions $z=0$ and $z=1$ and a polynomila of degree $6$ that Icall $pz$.

```
(%i8) gbz:gb[2];
(%o8) -81*z^11-243*z^10-27*z^9+495*z^8+279*z^7-255*z^6-148*z^5-19*z^4-z^3
(%i9) ss:solve(gbz,z);
(%o9) [z = 1,z = 0,0 = 81*z^6+405*z^5+756*z^4+612*z^3+189*z^2+21*z+1]
(%i10) pz:rhs(ss[3]);
(%o10) 81*z^6+405*z^5+756*z^4+612*z^3+189*z^2+21*z+1
```

$pz$ contains only roots with multiplicity $1$ because $pz$ and its first derivate are relatively prime.

```
(%i11) dpz:diff(pz,z);
(%o11) 486*z^5+2025*z^4+3024*z^3+1836*z^2+378*z+21
(%i12) gcd(pz,dpz);
(%o12) 1
```

It contains two real roots. "nroots" uses the method of Sturm sequences.

```
(%i13) nroots(pz);
(%o13) 2
```

For $z=0$ we get the solution $x=0$ and $y=0$. For $z=1$ we get $x=1$ and $y=1$.

```
(%i14) ev(solve(gb,[x,y]),z = 0);
(%o14) [[x = 0,y = 0]]
(%i15) ev(solve(gb,[x,y]),z = 1);
(%o15) [[x = 1,y = 1]]
```

So these are solutions that do not satisfy $x \ne y \ne z \ne x$. 
These are the only solution that satisfy $x=y$. 
That is shown by the following, where the Groebner basis that contains only the variable z has only the zeros $z=0$ and $z=1$:

```
(%i16) gbeq:poly_reduced_grobner([p1,p2,p3,x-y],[x,y,z])
(%o16) [z^2-z^3,3*z^2-z-2*x,3*z^2-z-2*y]
```

In a similar way it can be shown that there are no further solutions with $y=z$ or $z=x$.

```
(%i17) gbeq:poly_reduced_grobner([p1,p2,p3,y-z],[x,y,z])
(%o17) [y-z,z^2-z^3,3*z^2-2*z-x]
(%i18) gbeq:poly_reduced_grobner([p1,p2,p3,z-x],[x,y,z])
(%o18) [z-x,z^3-z^2,3*z^2-2*z-y]
```

So the the solutions of $pz(z)=0$ satisfy  $x \ne y \ne z \ne x$.

All in all we have proven that there are two solutions that satisfy the requirements.

Until now all the calculations where in integer arithmetic and therefore precise without any rounding errors. 
To find and approximation of the zeros of the polynomial we try to find an approximation solution (Jenkins algorithm)

```
%i19) rr:allroots(pz)
(%o19) [z = 0.059594592729233*%i-0.077325282882167,
        z = -0.059594592729233*%i-0.077325282882167,z = -0.34384834895616,
        z = -1.430213435919199,z = 0.52519906053201*%i-1.535643824680153,
        z = -0.52519906053201*%i-1.535643824680153]
```

The 3rd and the 4th of the found roots are real. We calculate the corresponding $x$ and $y$ values from the two polynomials of the Groebner basis

```
(%i20) ratprint:false
(%i21) ev(ss1:solve([gb[1],gb[3]],[x,y]),rr[3],numer)
(%o21) [[x = 0.33672111094963,y = -0.7012677966684]]
(%i22) ev(ss2:solve([gb[1],gb[3]],[x,y]),rr[4],numer)
(%o22) [[x = 0.68673203477216,y = -0.70126779745501]]
```

So finally we get the following approximations for the other real solutions:

```
(%i23) t1:endcons(rr[3],ss1[1])
(%o23) [x = 0.33672111094963,y = -0.7012677966684,z = -0.34384834895616]
(%i24) t2:endcons(rr[4],ss2[1])
(%o24) [x = 0.68673203477216,y = -0.70126779745501,z = -1.430213435919199]
```

To check the solutions we substitute them in the original  polynomials

```
(%i25) ev([p1,p2,p3],t1)
(%o25) [-1.9972772102860858E-8,-5.898479010779667E-9,-2.5471788220321478E-9]
(%i26) ev([p1,p2,p3],t2)
(%o26) [-1.4202621745340593E-8,5.3206585803877715E-9,-1.4270534975935334E-8]
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3-D $(x,y,z)$ problem can be reduced to a 2-D problem by substituting $\;z = 3xy-x-y\;$
into $\;x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3yz\;$ and $\;x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 3xz\,$ , giving the curves $\;\color{red}{f(x,y) = 0}\;$ and $\;\color{green}{g(x,y) = 0}\;$ where $f$ and $g$ are defined by:
$$
f(x,y) = 2 x^2 + 5 y^2 + 9 x^2 y^2 - 6 x^2 y - 15 x y^2 + 5 x y\\
g(x, y) = 27 x^3 y^3 - 27 x^3 y^2 - 27 x^2 y^3 + 9 x^3 y + 18 x^2 y^2
       + 9 x y^3 - 12 x^2 y - 3 x y^2 + 3 x^2 + 3 x y$$
A picture says more than a thousand words:

[image]

Note that $x$ is a factor of $g(x,y)$ , hence the $\color{green}{green}$ y-axis. Also note that there are trivial solutions $(x,y,z) = \{(0,0,0),(1,1,1)\}\;$ and that the trivial solution $\,(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)\,$ is invisible.
The two non-trivial points where the two curves intersect are found numerically with MAPLE :

```
fsolve({f(x,y)=0,g(x,y)=0},{x,y},{x=0.5..1,y=-1..-0.5});
fsolve({f(x,y)=0,g(x,y)=0},{x,y},{x=0..0.5,y=-1..-0.5});
```

Our solution is (but not quite) in agreement with the answer found by
[miracle173](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/11206/miracle173) :
$$
\left\{x = 0.6867320382, y = -0.7012678009, z = -1.430213436 \right\}\\
\left\{x = 0.3367211174, y = -0.7012678009, z = -0.343848349 \right\}
$$

But ah, what the OP probably wants is an *analytical solution*. So here comes / MAPLE says:
$$
 \left\{ x={\frac {1}{72}}\,{\frac {9\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5}
 \right) ^{4/3}-48\,\sqrt {5}-48\,\sqrt [3]{12+4\,\sqrt {5}}+3\,\sqrt 
{9\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{8/3}-96\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5}
 \right) ^{4/3}\sqrt {5}-96\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{5/3}-
3840+512\,\sqrt {5}\sqrt [3]{12+4\,\sqrt {5}}+1536\, \left( 12+4\,
\sqrt {5} \right) ^{2/3}-320\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{4/3}-
3072\,\sqrt {5}+768\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{2/3}\sqrt {5}}}
{ \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{2/3}}},y=-1/6\,\sqrt [3]{12+4\,
\sqrt {5}}-2/3\,{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{12+4\,\sqrt {5}}}} \right\} 
$$ $$
 \left\{ x={\frac {1}{72}}\,{\frac {9\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5}
 \right) ^{4/3}-48\,\sqrt {5}-48\,\sqrt [3]{12+4\,\sqrt {5}}-3\,\sqrt 
{9\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{8/3}-96\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5}
 \right) ^{4/3}\sqrt {5}-96\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{5/3}-
3840+512\,\sqrt {5}\sqrt [3]{12+4\,\sqrt {5}}+1536\, \left( 12+4\,
\sqrt {5} \right) ^{2/3}-320\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{4/3}-
3072\,\sqrt {5}+768\, \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{2/3}\sqrt {5}}}
{ \left( 12+4\,\sqrt {5} \right) ^{2/3}}},y=-1/6\,\sqrt [3]{12+4\,
\sqrt {5}}-2/3\,{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{12+4\,\sqrt {5}}}} \right\} 
$$
And $z$ can be calculated from $\;z = 3xy-x-y\;$ . Whatever .. What we see is that the $y$-coordinates of the two solutions are indeed exactly the same and I would like to hear a *simple* argument for this.